# How do I use apoc with the neo4j test container?

Tags: unit-testing, neo4j, neo4j-apoc, testcontainers

I believe I have enabled the apoc for the neo4j test container.

```
   @Container
    private static Neo4jContainer<?> neo4j = new Neo4jContainer<>(DockerImageName.parse("neo4j:4.2.14-enterprise"))
            .withAdminPassword(password)
            .withNeo4jConfig("dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted", "apoc.*")
            .withEnv("NEO4JLABS_PLUGINS", "[\\\"apoc\\\"]")
            .withEnv("NEO4J_ACCEPT_LICENSE_AGREEMENT", "yes")
            .withReuse(true);
```

Here is the pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>testcontainers</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

However, when I try to run my unit tests I get the follow error:

org.neo4j.driver.exceptions.ClientException: There is no procedure with the name `apoc.periodic.iterate` registered for this database instance. Please ensure you've spelled the procedure name correctly and that the procedure is properly deployed.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Testcontainers Neo4j module [documentation](https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/neo4j/#add-neo4j-docker-labs-plugins) you can use a special method `withLabsPlugins()` instead of your `NEO4JLABS_PLUGINS` environment variable. Like:

```java
...
.withLabsPlugins(Neo4jLabsPlugin.APOC)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more complete answer based on the helpful answer already posted by @yuppie-flu (which is in turn based on the `testcontainers` doc here: https://java.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/neo4j/#add-neo4j-docker-labs-plugins).

The most terse example for enabling APOC in your `testcontainers` instance is to include `.withLabsPlugins(Neo4jLabsPlugin.APOC)` when newing up a `Neo4jContainer`, like this:

```
@Container
private static final Neo4jContainer<?> neo4jContainer = new Neo4jContainer<>(imageName)
            .withLabsPlugins(Neo4jLabsPlugin.APOC); // <-- this enables APOC
```

Here is a more complete example. The general usage of this code is to call `TestGraph.getSession()` from any of your tests. This will either spin up a new testcontainers instance, or re-use whatever is already running in the current JVM.

```
import org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration;
import org.neo4j.ogm.session.Session;
import org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory;

import org.testcontainers.containers.Neo4jContainer;
import org.testcontainers.containers.Neo4jLabsPlugin;
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Container;
import org.testcontainers.utility.DockerImageName;

public class TestGraph {

    @Container
    private static final Neo4jContainer<?> neo4jContainer;

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static {
        DockerImageName imageName = DockerImageName.parse("neo4j:5.17.0");
        neo4jContainer = new Neo4jContainer<>(imageName)
                .withLabsPlugins(Neo4jLabsPlugin.APOC)  // <-- this enables APOC
                .withoutAuthentication();

        neo4jContainer.start();

        String boltUrl = neo4jContainer.getBoltUrl();

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration.Builder()
                .uri(boltUrl)
                .build();

        sessionFactory = new SessionFactory(configuration, "your.package.here");

    }

    public static Session getSession() {
        return sessionFactory.openSession();
    }
}
```